# Get return value from a function that uses ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following code:

```
function test() {

 $.when(MyModule.loadData("breadcrumbs", "BreadcrumbsData", jsndata, 'GET')).then(
   function (data) {

      return data;
   });
}

var result = test();
```

Problem: I am not getting the data in 'result' variable.

I am using Jquery 3.x.

MyModule.loadData is a method that executes a synchronous ajax request and returns the jqXHR object.

Thanks.

Comment: what returns MyModule.loadData("breadcrumbs", "BreadcrumbsData", jsndata, 'GET') ? one or multiple promises ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test() {

 return $.when(MyModule.loadData("breadcrumbs", "BreadcrumbsData", jsndata, 'GET')).then(
   function (data) {
      return data;
   });
}

var result;
test().then(function(data){
    result = data;
}).then(function(){
    console.log(result);
});
```